Any way that I can append a data along with a EVM smart contract transaction?
I want to append some data along with the Ethereum contract call. for example, tokenContract.approve.
I understand we can add the plain data to data field when we do a plain transaction. Just like this post mentioned.
But what if I want to append a data along with that certain contract code, in this case, .approve?
I tried to append a 32 bytes string to the .approve calldata just like below. But it looks like EVM does not like this format.
const additionalSlot = '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001';
const approveData = tokenContract.interface.encodeFunctionData('approve', [poolContract.address, amount]);

I ended up getting the following error.
Error: hex data is odd-length (argument="value", value="0x095ea7b30000000000000000000000008fe3842e0b7472a57f2a2d56cf6bce08517a1de000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f424000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.5.0)

I want to ask for a hint, please!!
Update 20240808
The length of additionalSlot mentioned above is 65, I guess it should be 64 (32 bytes). So I removed one 0 to make it 32 bytes.
However, I still cannot make it work. The different error is thrown like below:
Message: Invalid token value; should be exactly 64 hex digits long (u256)

Code: Error

Stack:
Error: Invalid token value; should be exactly 64 hex digits long (u256)
  at n.getCustomTxParamsData (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/ui-7.js:1:27164)
  at z (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/ui-7.js:1:229340)
  at ba (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-5.js:1:288767)
  at Is (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-5.js:1:333598)
  at Ru (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-5.js:1:319506)
  at Au (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-5.js:1:319431)
  at Tu (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-5.js:1:316779)
  at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-5.js:1:275177
  at r.unstable_runWithPriority (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-6.js:3:13158)
  at Qi (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-5.js:1:274886)
  at eo (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-5.js:1:275122)
  at Yi (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-5.js:1:275057)
  at yu (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-5.js:1:313545)
  at Ra (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-5.js:1:292424)
  at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/ui-7.js:1:114253



NOTE: The new calldata hex string is 0x095ea7b30000000000000000000000008fe3842e0b7472a57f2a2d56cf6bce08517a1de000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f4240000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a
(I also tried adding one more leading zero to make the length 66 (33 bytes). But still no luck with the same error message.

Not sure if I am missing anything. Any hint will be appreciated.)
Let me share the code section below:
// Assuming you already have a provider object to sign transaction
// The ethersjs version being used is "^5.5.4"
const erc20ABI = [
  "function decimals() public view returns (uint8)",
  "function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance)",
  "function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)",
  "function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256)",
  "function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)",
  "function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256)",
  "function totalDeposits() external view returns (uint256)",
  "event Transfer(from, to, value)"
]
const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract('the-erc20-token-addr', erc20ABI, provider.getSigner());
const amount = ethers.utils.parseUnits('1', decimals);
const additionalSlot = '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001';
const approveData = tokenContract.interface.encodeFunctionData('approve', ['<target-contract-adress>', amount]);

const modifiedApproveData = approveData + additionalSlot;
console.log('approveData', modifiedApproveData);
const approveTransaction = await provider.getSigner().sendTransaction({
  to: tokenContract.address,
  data: modifiedApproveData
});

Or , the simplest approach, connect the metamask wallet to any Arbitrum DAPP (the chain I am working on). Open chrome browser dev tool, and pass in the following code:
window.ethereum.request({
    method: "eth_sendTransaction",
    params: [{
        from: 'your-connected-wallet-addr',
        to: '0xaf88d065e77c8cC2239327C5EDb3A432268e5831', // USDC addr
        // Manipulate the data if you want
        data: '0x095ea7b30000000000000000000000008fe3842e0b7472a57f2a2d56cf6bce08517a1de000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f42400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
    }]
})


Can you share your minimal reproducible code snippet, so that I can try debugging on my end?

Sure, @SYEDASADKAZMI, I have added that js script to the end of the main section. Feel free to let me know if I miss anything.
Just FYI, if I do not append the additionalSlot to calldata, there will be no error at all.

Update the code again adding the contract instantiated section. This way, you do not need to create redundant ERC20 ABI.

I think the issue is when doing using the BrowserProvider (or injected provider) i.e., MetaMask in your case. Because using the JsonRpcProvider, it's working fine on my end, in both the cases i.e., using 64 hex characters as well as 66 hex characters in additionalSlot.

And, most probably, that's happening because MetaMask has put its own validation on any token related transactions for security purposes.

Hmm, that makes sense, yeah ... so it means we are not able to do such kind of operation if we use metamask ( or even other browser extension),

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The error message indicates that the hex data is of odd length, which means the hexadecimal string you are trying to process has an incorrect number of characters. Hexadecimal strings should have an even number of characters, as each pair of characters represents a single byte.
In your code, the problematic value seems to be this hex string:
0x095ea7b30000000000000000000000008fe3842e0b7472a57f2a2d56cf6bce08517a1de000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f424000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001

You have defined additionalSlot as 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001, which is an odd-length string. When combined with other data to form the final hex string, it causes the error.
To fix this issue, make sure the additionalSlot value is an even-length string.
In your case, it's length is 65 hex characters, so you can remove an extra zero from the beginning so as to make its length as 64 hex characters or add an extra zero in the beginning so as to make its length as 66 hex characters:
const additionalSlot = '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'; // Note the removed leading zero

This should ensure the resulting hex string has an even number of characters, resolving the error.
Here's the code snippet using the same ethers.js version (i.e., 5.5.4) as mentioned in the question:
const ethers = require('ethers');
require("@chainlink/env-enc").config();

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('RPC_URL')

const signer = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, provider);

const contractAddress = "TOKEN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS";

const approvingAddress = "APPROVING_ADDRESS";

const abi = [
    "function decimals() public view returns (uint8)",
    "function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance)",
    "function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)",
    "function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256)",
    "function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)",
    "function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256)",
    "function totalDeposits() external view returns (uint256)",
    "event Transfer(from, to, value)"
]

const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi);

const amount = ethers.utils.parseUnits('1', 18);
const additionalSlot = '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001';
const approveData = tokenContract.interface.encodeFunctionData('approve', [approvingAddress, amount]);

console.log(additionalSlot.length);
const modifiedApproveData = approveData + additionalSlot;
console.log('approveData', modifiedApproveData);

signer.sendTransaction({
    to: contractAddress,
    data: modifiedApproveData
}).then(async (approveTransaction) => {
    const rc = await approveTransaction.wait();
    console.log(rc.transactionHash);
});

NOTE: Adding extra data (especially in case of token transactions) doesn't seem to be possible when using an injected provider (like MetaMask) because it has its own validation on any token-related transactions.

Thanks for the reply. I tried to add a leading zero (also remove one zero) so that the  additionalSlot length becomes 66 (also 64).
However, different error still occurs like below
Message: Invalid token value; should be exactly 64 hex digits long (u256)

Let me add the detailed into Update 02040808 on main section
